# Office 365 SMTP encryption

Tags: smtp, microsoft-office-365

AFAIK Outlook is using `POP/IMAP` protocol to access mails in `Office 365`. I occasionally have seen instructions for 3rd product integrations with `Office 365` that required configuration of `mail routing rules` so that messages are forwarded to security devices (for instance `SMTP proxies` where the mail is inspected and sent back to `Office 365`). I guess that protocol used to send the email to the security device is SMTP but how can I know whether the connection between `Office 365 --> SMTP Porxy --> Office 365` are actually encrypted ?

Answer (score 3):

> AFAIK Outlook is using POP/IMAP protocol to access mails in Office 365.

Ah. No? Yeah. No. It is NOT using POP/IMAP to sync Outlook.

Outlook uses a proprietary protocol that also handles other things that none of those standards do.

> but how can I know whether the connection between Office 365 --> SMTP Porxy --> Office 
>   365 are actually encrypted ?

It is not because it is not SMTP, unless you talk of 2 different organizations. Exchange server - the technolgoy behind - is smart enough that SMTP is not used when sending emails in the same environment. As SMTP is not used, the question is moot.

THAT SAID: between different environments (and I do not know whether O365 is one environment or multiple - it is one for a customer, but it is a LOT of customers) SMTP may be used - then without encryption, but that is standard on the internet. Emails you send to gmail or any other company are also not encrypted.

Comment: Okay got it. But when I need to send the e-mail out a cloud based provider for content inspection that would use plain SMTP, right ?

Comment: @cyzczy If you use a product like a third part antispam's product on top of o365, usually the email would flow encrypted in TLS to it

Comment: Generally - emails on the internet using SMTP are not encrypted. If you need security, send encrypted emails (which the third party provider then acutally cna not parse). Is this a security issue? Bet on it - but SMTP is ancient. 3rd party providers MAY at least mitigate this by integrating properly into O365 - i.e. the traffic does not have to leave at least microsoft ;) Takes off a lot of security issues not to cross the internet (and between MS installations you use encrypted lines).

Comment: But if I enforce SMTP over TLS between my mail server and the receiving server, the connection is encrypted, right ?

Comment: Between your servers and the receiving servers - most of which may not even accept SMTP over TLS, you know.